# unable to create pdf from multiple html files in python inside ADO pipeline

Tags: python, azure, devops, pipeline, wkhtmltopdf

unable to create pdf from multiple html files in python inside ADO pipeline, but if I pass one single file then the report is being generated.

inside bash:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo apt-get install -y wkhtmltopdf
```

Python script:

```
frontPage =  os.path.join(fileName, 'frontPage.html')
index = os.path.join(fileName, 'index.html')
```

```
// providing 1 file
pdfkit.from_file([fileName],"report.pdf") //works perfectly fine

// providing multiple files
pdfkit.from_file([frontPage, index],"report1.pdf") //showing error
```

error:
but for single HTML file, report is being created in artifacts.and the path of the HTML files are correct.

[image]

expecting to generate PDF with multiple htmls